# Last column 'NULL' Strings not being replaced by NULL in Greenplum

Tags: postgresql, null, greenplum

I have a text file demo.txt with the following data:

```
1|John|23|Male|None
2|David|None|MALE|California
3|Katie|None|FEMALE|None
```

All of the columns in this file are text

I am trying to load the txt file in postgres using this

```
CREATE READABLE EXTERNAL TEMP TABLE ashish
        (
        Serial varchar(255),
        Name varchar(255),
        Age varchar(255),
        Gender varchar(6),
        State varchar(255)
        )
LOCATION
(
'<path>/demo.txt'
)
    FORMAT 'text' (delimiter E'\t' null 'None') ENCODING 'UTF8';
        CREATE TEMP TABLE demo as 
        SELECT * from ashish
        distributed by (Serial);
```

The result I get is:

[image]

Question: Why does my code not replace the 'None' of the last column and make it NULL like it did for 'Age' column?

I have workarounds for that, but I want to know the issue in this code.

Comment: Could there be an additional character appended to `None` in the final column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, there is not. I checked that.

Comment: Can you try putting the delimeter after the `state` column?  My resources here are limited, but I think there is an issue with the delimiter you are using?

Comment: `CREATE READABLE EXTERNAL TEMP TABLE` is not standard Postgres syntax. Which DBMS are you really using? What does `select version()` show?

Comment: "PostgreSQL 8.2.15 (Greenplum Database 4.2.8.3 build 1) on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.4.2 compiled on Nov  2 2014 01:33:14"  @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Do you mean adding a delimiter in the text file? That is not possible as I am working with a very large file (1GB) and anyway I am not allowed to edit the file. Let me know if I got it wrong and if you meant modification in the code.